# Files getting deleted after 21 days in SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have an attachment in the SFTP folder which gets attached to an email using =%%Attachfile

MC however removes files from SFTP after 21 days. Is there a way around this where they dont delete this file?
What would be a plan B for this. Can we save this file into our local server & use AMPscript to point to the new location?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enhanced_ftp_guide.htm&type=5
“Marketing Cloud retains your files on Marketing Cloud SFTP for at least 21 days. Any file that is older than 21 days is eligible for removal, and we can remove files after 21 days.”

Answer (score 1):

You can check with Salesforce Support, if they can extend this period beyond 21 days. However a better solution might be to store it in a different location and attach it via HTTP, instead of FTP:

```
%%[
SET @filepath = Concat('http://example.com/catalog_.pdf')
]%%
%%=AttachFile('HTTP',@filepath,'product_catalog.pdf',true,'@filepath','Click here to download your catalog',4)=%%
```

Comment: Support would not be able to extend this period